# Downloaded picture doesn't fit ImageView although the size should be ok (novoda)

Tags: android, android-imageview, support-image-loader

I download a static map from Google Maps Static API. When I download the image in browser, the size is ok (728x224). You can check the url from below.

But when I try to view it in my android app it's to small (540x166). Of course I could display it with 'centerCrop' but it's not ideal solution. As far as I know, both sizes are in pixels so it should fit perfectly. I log it this way:

```
 Log.i(TAG, "view size: "+mapPicture.getWidth()+"/"+mapPicture.getHeight());
 Log.i(TAG, "pic size: "+mapPicture.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+"/"+mapPicture.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());
```

And the logcat looks like this:

```
11-29 21:41:37.547: I/DetailsFragment(18064): view size: 728/224
11-29 21:41:37.547: I/DetailsFragment(18064): http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=3&size=364x112&scale=2&sensor=false
11-29 21:41:37.547: I/DetailsFragment(18064): pic size: 540/166
```

I download the image with [ImageManager](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader) and test on a hdpi device.

**So why the downloaded pic has different size than it should?**

**Edit:**
When I download an image twice as big, the drawable inside the `ImageView` is almost the same size as previously: `pic size: 540/189`

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=52.2396,21.0174&zoom=14&size=729x225&scale=2&sensor=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29)?

> **Note**: Prior to **JELLY_BEAN**, this function would not correctly retrieve
>   the final configuration density when the resource ID passed here is an
>   alias to another Drawable resource. This means that if the density
>   configuration of the alias resource is different than the actual
>   resource, the density of the returned Drawable would be incorrect,
>   resulting in bad scaling. To work around this, you can instead
>   retrieve the Drawable through TypedArray.getDrawable. Use
>   Context.obtainStyledAttributes with an array containing the resource
>   ID of interest to create the TypedArray

Comment: No i didn't. And I think I'll have to read it 5 times to understand this workaround. But it looks like an exact explanation to my problem.

Comment: So novoda ImageManager downloads image, uses the function you mentioned to get the drawable. And it's the point where the problem occurs. Without changing the code behind the loader I will be unable to resolve it. It scales it down, and when I use `centerCrop` scales up again which results in quality loss. That's weird. Thanks anyway and if you can come up with a solution (and not simply downloading a higher res image), I'd be grateful